# Using git with config files

Tags: git

I develop locally and push to a remote server where production system is located.

Source code files in my local development instance and in the remote production instance should be identical, however config files should not. But I still want to keep track of both of them.

I don't want to have separate files like `config.prod` and `config.dev` because in production environment `config.dev` is useless and shouldn't be present; and because different people working on the same project may have different local configs.

Is this possible to achieve with `git`? Do I need to set up additional repositories? What should structure of my folders look like then?

Comment: You could have 2 git repos with main source as a submodule of both.

Comment: @alex Could you explain in a little more detail?